# Is it true that the bubbles do not touch each other in the boiling water while going up?

Tags: water, bubbles

I heard once that the bubbles do not touch when the water is boiling. I want to know if that is actually happening, and I would be interested to hear why it is true or not.

Comment: No big deal, but to be fair, you should indicate an amended qestion, when  your initial question is answered. Anyway, at the start of boiling,  it's obvious enough that bubbles could start to rise seperately. So your question is   based around time of formation of bubbles.